# Stereoscopic side-by-side picture

Tags: rendering, stereoscopy

I want to make side-by-side images that anyone can view and see in 3D by doing the "magic eye" trick or cross-eye. I have some Blender models already and tried enabling stereoscopic 3d side by side in output, but i get an error that the "camera" is not a multi-view camera.
Is there no easy way to just open a Blender scene and tell it to render a side-by-side image that works like this?

I've searched and not found anything clear about how to do this simply. It's confusing!

I have dozens of hours in Blender, but it's been a few months so I'm a little rusty...

Comment: The Blender manual section on Stereoscopy is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/render/output/properties/stereoscopy/index.html#stereoscopy).